# Vs Code nx console generate command not working : This command has no flags to set

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm have nx console extension installed in my Vs Code and upon trying to use the generate command (generate component, service, library etc.) its saying "*ng generate @schematics/angular:component
This command has no flags to set*" . I don't want to write the commands manually since it is time consuming. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the extension, closing my VsCode but i still get the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved it.. turns out my nx console had just upgraded itself to a newer and less stable version.
To solve this go to your extensions panel on vs code find nx console extension and click on the settings icon at the bottom right.
And select **Install another version** then choose any lesser version then reload your window

Answer (score 4):

The latest version has a problem. Install a previous one - `17.13.7`, it works

[image]

Answer (score 1):

version 17.14.0 of extension nx-console has problem. Just install another and wait for new fix

Comment: How I can install another version?

Comment: @gesiud see my answer

Answer (score 0):

By me it solved by uninstalling other extensions.

Comment: You for real man? :D :D :D

Comment: Yea,I do not know which one it was. Seems it had an conflict.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I didn't notice it automatically flag --dry-run in the command generated, the change only after after click `Generate`. My fault on not reading the text carefully :v !